SSRS 2022 with ODPM ( ODP.Net) 19.21 select userenv('LANG') result random change between ZHT and US
We are currently  at  SSRS 2022  pre-upgrade,  verify compatibility stage.
While querying the Oracle E-Business Suite 11i (ERP 11i) database (Oracle 11.2.0.4 DB), we are using the Oracle ODP.Net Managed Driver (ODPM) 19.21 version.
Currently, we are encountering the following issues:
The Oracle ERP database supports multi-language configurations. In previous versions of ODP.Net, the NLS_LANG setting referred to the NLS_LANG Windows Registry.
However, the ODP.Net Managed Driver does not support using NLS_LANG.
During testing, we discovered the following problems with SSRS + ODPM 19.21:
The USERENV('LANG') result from the database keep change  between ZHT and US  ( Language ).
And if setting the "Language Property" of the Paginated Report to "en-US".
It doesn't work with ODPM too.
The SSRS not passing "report language" to ODPM.
Regards,
Wilson Shen
The  SSRS Report Data Set SQL : " select userenv('LANG') from dual " should be keep return "US" value.

I guess the only option is an ALTER SESSION SET NLS_LANGUAGE = ... command to run after you established the connection.

Hi Wernfried Domscheit,
Thank for your kindly.  This is a solution. But how could SSRS do that ?

Hi Wernfried Domscheit,
Thank you for your kind reply. This is a solution. But how can SSRS achieve this?
I have another idea: asking the DBA to add a login trigger to force the session's NLS_LANGUAGE to AMERICAN.
Are there any other solutions ?
Best regards,
Wilson

Did you check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/set-the-locale-for-a-report-or-text-box-reporting-services?view=sql-server-ver16 ? I have no clue about SSRS.
